# Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration

When I publish my website to my plesk server I get an error about a:

> Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel.

Comment: I think marc_s is correct, but please post your full error message

Answer (score 11):

What version of the .NET framework does your hoster support??

The `<system.serviceModel>` is the WCF section and WCF only came about in .NET 3.0 - if this hoster is only supporting strictly .NET 2.0, then you're out of luck :-(

Solutions:

- either you can get your hosting provider to install .NET 3.0 (or preferably .NET 3.5 SP1) so you can use WCF
- you remove that `<system.serviceModel>` section from your config file if you don't even need and use WCF

Answer (score 2):

The error message:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel. (c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config line 146)

is probably caused by missing WCF section handlers. [Wenlong Dong1 explains](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2010/11/23/why-does-machine-config-contain-invalid-xml-content-after-installing-net-3-5-patches/) in more detail, what might be going on.

In my case I could restore the sections by running the solution steps for what he calls issue 2, that is:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\WFServicesReg.exe /r /b

"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" /i

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\WFServicesReg.exe /c /b
```

Comment: Those three lines fixed it for us as well.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this error while trying to install one of my company's standard products, that I just couldn't get working (it's an ASP.NET 2.0 website).  I found that within the C# code it references System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["our param name"].

I went in to IIS Admin (it's on Windows XP/SP3), the ASP.NET tab  and 'Edit Configuration', and when I got to the Application tab, it just threw an unhandled exception as above, "Unexpected section system.serviceModel in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config".

I deleted the section from machine.config, and all was well, the website was able to come up as expected.

Although, to add further confusion, I have a second machine running the same web application, which also has the "system.serviceModel" section, and that works fine.  Both machines have .Net 1.1, 2.0SP2, 3.0SP2 and 3.5SP1 installed.  There's obviously a bit more to this, but just deleting the section appears to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Symantec Backup Exec has also problems with this.

Solution:
Removed
    
              all inclusive

And works fine.

Link:
[The Backup Exec for Windows Servers console does not open](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH68868)

Answer (score 0):

We have two load-balanced web servers with basically identical configurations, and one of them started receiving this error after installing Windows Updates last night (1/29/2013).

I copied the machine.config file from the working machine, and it appears that everything is now working correctly.