# WebORB for .NET - Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel in webconfig.xml

Tags: .net, windows, iis, weborb

I'm facing a problem trying to install WebORB 4.5 and running its administration console.

Since install with the exe doesn't work at all, I do the [zip install process](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v4/guide/index.html) .
When I want to access the console (step #3), I get a lots of errors popups "Send failed..."

Running diagnosics tells me that there is a configuration error :

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel.

Source Error: 
Line 121:  </system.webServer>
Line 122:    
Line 123:  <system.serviceModel>                
Line 124:    
Line 125:    <services>        

Source File: C:\Program Files\WebORB for .NET\4.5.0.31\web.config    Line: 123
```

My current configuration :

- OS : Windows 2000 server
- .Net : 2.0.50727 SP2
- WebORB : 4.5.0.31

I wasn't able to find an precise answer on other forums yet but I think that's not only a WebORB issue. I've seen that *system.serviceModel* [is not supported before .Net 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100825/1179879) but since WebORB 4.5 gives the opportunity to use .Net 2.0 version during install, I wonder what to do... If I remove the *system.serviceModel*, it doesn't work either.

Need help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found elsewhere the answer so I put it here, it will maybe help someone :) I have to thank [Mark Miller (Weborb)](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/forum/Default.aspx?g=posts&m=14513#14513) for this trick.

What I have understood is that when automatic install with EXE is not possible, you have to deal with the ZIP installation.

Doing so, Weborb install folder [WEBORB DIR] will contain these 2 important files **\bin\weborb.dll** and **\Web.config**.

If by default, they are not configured to work for your .NET version (I think it's 3.5 by default) you will have to make a few changes.

If like me, you have to install it on a server running .NET 2.0, in your WebORB installation you will find an assembly (dll) for 2.0 at the following location:

```
[WEBORB DIR]\weborbassets\weborbbuilds\.NET2.0\bin
```

There is also web.config located at:

```
[WEBORB DIR]\weborbassets\weborbbuilds\.NET2.0\
```

Then, you will have to copy this correct **weborb.dll** into [WEBORB DIR]\bin
and also to copy **web.config** into [WEBORB DIR]\

Doing this, I was finally able to load Weborb console without any error!